# "puts" output not displaying in Heroku logs for Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, puts

I'm trying to use "puts" to test a few things with a Sinatra app that's hosted on Heroku. Interestingly, the output seems to queue up and only displays upon restarting the Heroku dyno. I've tried with 'Thin' and 'Webrick', but have the same issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It does work on Heroku. Are you using Heroku's log monitor?

Comment: Using Heroku logs, yes. That's how I can see the output upon restarting the dyno.

Comment: You might just need to sync stdout. Try adding `$stdout.sync = true` early in your apps startup (top of `config.ru` is a good place).

Answer (score 38):

As you can see on [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log): add this to your config.ru:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```

Don't forget the `$` before `stdout` or it won't work.

Comment: Thank you! I missed this in the docs and couldn't work out why I wasn't seeing my logs.